# Not in GZIP format error when set value to f:setPropertyActionListener jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, gzip

I have one error after I modify the value of f:setPropertyActionListener by jquery like that :

```
$('#javax\\.faces\\.ViewState').val("1111111");
```

I inspected the element to know its id (it is transformed to hidden input)

here is the jsf element  :

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{typeMB.supprimer}"  value="supprimer" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="typeMB.selectedIdType" value="dcscdc" />
    </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

then in the code source of the page : the value is affected but the method "supprimer" doesn't be executed and I have this error  :

```
 mars 19, 2013 3:33:12 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper doGetState
SEVERE: Not in GZIP format
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:78)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doGetState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:231)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.getState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:198)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.getState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
```

how can I resolve it

thank you in advance

Comment: You're not modifying the value of `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`. You're modifying the value of `<input type="hidden" id="javax.faces.ViewState">`. Are you absolutely sure that you know what you're doing? This question indicates that you don't. Please elaborate the concrete functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that this would be the right solution instead of posting code which doesn't make sense in real world and asking a wrong question about it.

Comment: I want to modify the value attribute of `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` by jquery (not with ajax as the case of jsf)

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I just asked for the **why**. This is namely totally not possible. Once you elaboate the **why** in detail, then we can propose the right solution. The **why** is the concrete functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that this is the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the value of `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` by jQuery. This information is not printed anywhere into the HTML output (rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to see it yourself) and therefore also not manipulatable by JS/jQuery. Your current jQuery attempt only modifies the hidden input field of the JSF view state identifier which is a huge no-no (and in turn indicates that you have no idea how basic JSF, HTTP and HTML works; I would at that point strongly recommend to temporarily stop developing JSF webapplications and go through some sane HTTP/HTML/JSF resources to learn about the basic matters first). The particular exception is a consequence of this mistake: you modified the JSF view state identifier to some arbitrary value which is not in the expected format.

You still didn't state the concrete functional requirement clearly, but if your sole intent is to pass a JavaScript-controlled variable as additional request parameter to JSF, then you should be looking for a different solution. One of the ways would be using `<h:inputHidden>`.

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:inputHidden id="hiddenId" value="#{typeMB.selectedIdType}" />
    <p:commandButton value="supprimer" onclick="yourFunction()" actionListener="#{typeMB.supprimer}" />
</h:form>
```

With this JS:

```
function yourFunction() {
    $("#formId\\:hiddenId").val("1111111");
}
```

Comment: now I explain more my goal : I noticed that primefaces use ajax in all its communication and in several cases I don't need to give the data from the server so I wanted to use the primefaces UI component but use also jquery when data can be retrieved from the current page